# How to get index of element by parent in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get index of div element from parent tree:

```js
$(".row .col a").click(function() {
  var e = $(this).parent();
  var p = e.parent();
  var i = p.index(e);
  console.log([e, p, i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><a>link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col"><a>link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But index is always -1. First link should be 0 and second link 1. How do you get index in this kind of html sctructure?

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('.col').index()`. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8nvnwvnp/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) get the index of the element in the parent. As there is only one element with `.row` class, `index()` returns the index `0` as it is zero-based.

To get the index of the clicked element, get the closest ancestor `.col` and call index on it.

```
$(this).closest('.col').index()
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8nvnwvnp/)

```js
$(".row .col a").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('.col').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><a>link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col"><a>link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```